# Lua print in same line

Tags: lua, lua-table

This is my code. I want to have output something like this
3,2,3 i.e values separated with commas in the same line instead of getting the values in new lines

my input is : @lua is fun

Thanks!

```
function countChar(s)
   words = {}
   for word in s:gmatch("%w+") 
   do 
       table.insert(words, word) 
       print(#word) 
   end
end
n = tonumber(io.read())
for i=1,n
do
    s=io.read();
    countChar(s)
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to concatenate some strings during your "for loop" and then print the results. Use a string variable and join the strings using `..` to add your commas you can simply use a string with a comma to concatenate that into the values as well.

Comment: `I want to have output something like this 3,2,3` do you mean input like `3,2,3`? it is unclear what you expect for an input and what you want as an output

Comment: To do this you will have to first input the all the words(without calling countChar function) and store them in list. Then pass this list to the countChar function. Inside the countChar function's for loop count the string lengths and create a new string to hold the comma separated lengths. After the for loop print the string with comma separated lengths.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with your code:

- the `words` table is not really used as is. You only need a table of lengths not a table of words themselves,
- "parsing" logic is not separated from the "user interface",
- there are no messages prompting for user input,
- unneeded global variables,
- it is also possible to guarantee that `n` is a number with `io.read ('*number', '*line')`,
- the word lengths can be printed in one line using `table.concat` on a table of word lengths.

This is my proposal addressing these issues:

```lua
local function countChar(s)
    local lengths = {}
    for word in s:gmatch '%w+' do 
        table.insert(lengths, word:len()) 
    end
    return lengths
end

io.write 'Number of sentences: '
local n = io.read('*number', '*line')

for i = 1, n do
    io.write ('Sentence no. ' .. tostring(i) .. ': ')
    local s = io.read()
    io.write ('Word lengths: ' .. table.concat(countChar(s), ', ') .. '\n')
end
```

In addition, it is not necessary to prompt the user for the number of sentences. Sentences can be read one by one until user just presses Enter, i.e. inserts an empty string. This solution uses a simple iterator that consumes user input and prints prompts:

```lua
local function countChar(s)
    local lengths = {}
    for word in s:gmatch '%w+' do 
        table.insert(lengths, word:len()) 
    end
    return lengths
end

local function getSentences()
    io.write ('Enter a sentence or just press Enter to finish: ')
    local input = io.read()
    if input == '' then
        input = nil -- this nil will stop the generic for loop below.
    end
    return input
end

for s in getSentences do
    io.write ('Word lengths: ' .. table.concat(countChar(s), ', ') .. '\n')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local function countChar( str )
    local numbers  = ''
    for word in str :gmatch( '%w+' ) do
        numbers = numbers ..#word ..','  --  concatenate
    end
    return numbers :sub( 1, -2 )  --  remove trailing comma
end

io.write( 'Phrase to count? ' )  --  @lua is fun
local phrase = io .read()
print(  countChar( phrase )  )
```

Phrase to count? @lua is fun
3,2,3